# jquery: remove previous class by clicking

Tags: jquery

I've a very simple question but can't figure it out by myself. 
i've the following problem.

i've several list items like below.

```
<li></li>
            <li>
                <img src="images/persoon1.jpg" alt="persoon1">
                <div id="infoPersoon">
                    <h3>Jaap-Jan van der Gouw</h3>
                    <ul id="contactInfo">
                        <li class="label">T</li>
                        <li>070 31 31 066</li>
                        <li class="label">F</li>
                        <li>070 31 31 066</li>
                        <li class="label">M</li>
                        <li>070 31 31 066</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul id="contactOpties">
                        <li class="email"><a href="#" class="active">Email</a></li>
                        <li class="publicaties"><a href="#">Publicaties</a></li>
                        <li class="vcard"><a href="#">Vcard</a></li>
                        <li class="meerinfo"><a href="#">Meer info</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li></li>
```

the problem is that i want to add a class by the current list i clicked on, and when i clicked to the next list item, the previous class "active" must be remove.

how can i solve that problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most common approach is to remove the active class from any tag that has it like:

```
$(".active").removeClass("active");
```

To put it all together would be:

```
$("li").click(function() {
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Sometimes i feel like stupid when i just can't figure this kind of simple things out.. thank you it worked very well!.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `click` handler like this:

```
$("#contactOpties li a").click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('active')
         .parent().siblings().children().removeClass('active');
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nwkJt/).  This adds the class only on click, but you could also toggle the `.active` class off if you clicked, do to that use [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) instead of [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).

---

Or just so you have options, you could have the click handler on the `<li>` or use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) (useful for *lots* of elements, or dynamically changing ones), like this:

```
$("#contactOpties").delegate("li", "click", function() {
  $(this).children('a').addClass('active').end()
         .siblings().children().removeClass('active');
});
```

[You can give that a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/nwkJt/2/).

Comment: This is the most effective way to do this as it handles everything you need with proper scope.

Comment: always prefer `.delegate()`. No need to waste `event handler functions`.

Comment: it only worked for me when I used ".siblings()" alone without appending other options .children() or  .parent()